# Are conference proceedings included in Springer's Lecture Notes on Computer Science considered to be indexed by Scopus or WebOS MJL?

Tags: conference, indexing, proceedings

I see that Springer's Lecture Notes on Computer Science (LNCS) is indexed both in Clarivate's Web of Science Master Journal List and Scopus. Does it mean that all the proceedings from conferences inside LNCS are regarded to be in equal status with the other journals that are indexed by both indexers?

Answer (score 2):

Whether a journal or conference has a high reputation or not is not directly connected with whether the journal or conference in indexed in such indices.

Rather, the indexing bodies define some minimum level of quality assurance and will not index anything that they believe to be below this level. There may also be highly reputable venues that are not indexed because of various reasons.

LNCS defines some minimum quality levels as well (for instance in terms of peer review), which seems to allow them to be included in these indices. The conferences whose proceedings appear as LNCS volumes still vary in terms of reputation, and such reputation also changes over time.

So they are not of "equal status" except perhaps for the scenario where some researcher may be assessed not by the quality of their work, but by the number of indexed publications.